# Flow checked React element and give me an error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I used `SectionIist` and add some props on it :
[image]

But when I use Flow to check my code. I got the following error:

[image]

It seems that `Flow` are checking the components offered by `react-native` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use your `keyExtractor` like `keyExtractor={(item, index) => your_title+index}`. I have added `index` for `unique key` purpose. Try as follows,

```
<SectionList 
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.title}_${index}`}
/>
```